# Libav: Rotate video then add overlay

Tags: libav, avconv

I'm trying to rotate a video and then add an overlay. But it's not working, I've tried a combination of things, and none has worked.

This is the closest I've gotten:

```
avconv -i VIDEO.mp4 -i OVERLAY.png -strict experimental -threads auto  -c:a copy -filter_complex "transpose=1;[0:v][1:v]overlay" OUT.mp4 -y
```

Problem is that this adds two separate streams to the container one rotated, and one with the logo!

Answer (score 0):

In a way this is exactly what you've asked it to do. You didn't actually map the needed stream correctly.

Here's what i managed to get working quickly on my machine:

```
avconv -i input.ogv -i logo.jpeg -an -filter_complex '[0:v]transpose=1[rv];[rv][1:v]overlay[final]' -map '[final]' -c:v libtheora out.ogv
```

Let's look at what's happening here.

1. -filter_complex takes two video streams [0:v] and [1:v]
2. I rotate [0:v] and store the result in [rv] (you can come up with any string here, i chose rv to mean "rotated video"
3. I then pass [rv] and [1:v] into the overlay and save the result into [final].

The problem at this point is that all the other streams are still lingering somewhere and are mapped to the output file. So i had to do `-map '[final']` in order to map the correct resultant string as the only video stream of output.

By default -filter_complex's filters store things back into stream names that they got, but in this case something just got confused. In either case you have no need to have two streams in the end anyhow.